# Apache Solr: How to delete items with empty ids?

Tags: apache, solr, document

The problem is I can't delete some items from Apache Solr 4.9.0 that have empty ID while all other fields are very similar to legitimate documents.

I checked on how to select such items, and select by `-id:["" TO *]` works pretty fine. Now I need to delete such docs, but

```
<delete><query>-id:["" TO *]</query></delete>
```

and

```
<delete><query>id:""</query></delete>
```

do nothing. What is the proper way to do delete such entries?

Comment: Is the `id` field present in your docs and is empty or does it not even exist in some docs?

Comment: Yes, id is present and is empty (query response below):

`<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"><doc><str name="id"/><str name="name">name</str><str name="description">desc</str><str name="location">49.98309,36.23121</str> ...`

Comment: May be you forgot to commit? Try this: `/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:""</query></delete>&commit=true`

Comment: @arun, thanks, id:"" works fine with commit=true!